# Copy Data In Excel And Paste To New Using Excel.Interop

Tags: c#, office-interop, excel-interop

I am attemtping to convert some vba code to C#.  I'm making pretty good progress, but the bottom two lines in my code are giving me errors.  What do I need to change so that this code will function as desired?

```
Application oApp = new Application();
Workbook wb = oApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Test\\Test Data.xlsx");
var firstSheet = (_Worksheet) wb.ActiveSheet;

Range last = firstSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
Range range = firstSheet.get_Range("A1", last);

int lastRow = last.Row;
int lastColumn = last.Column;

long outputColumn;
long tempCol1;
long tempCol2;
string dataVal;
string letterVal;
string decodedVal;

outputColumn = lastColumn + 1;
tempCol1 = lastColumn + 2;
tempCol2 = lastColumn + 3;

//this gives build errors
Excel.Columns(lastColumn).Copy(Excel.Columns(tempCol1));
Excel.Cells(1, tempCol1).Delete();
```

**EDIT**
The build error I get is
`` The name `Excel` does not exist in the current context ``

Comment: what kind of error do you get ?

Comment: @JDSN - ``The name `Excel` does not exist in the current context``